# Why segmentation fault occurs in further iterations of brute force

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a puzzle again! this is the link: http://www.puzzleup.com/2015/puzzle/?9

my method requires vectors. Because I use this method:

[image]

I valued all the corners, and I track each iteration thrugh the end(15 th corner). I start from 1 and record all the corners I ve been through in the possibilities 2d array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;

/*
possibilities will keep the possible combinations, routes like {1,4}{4,8}{8,7} etc till it arrives to 15
*/

vector< vector<int> > possibilities;

int cubes[15][6] = { {2,3,5,0,0,0}, {1,4,6,0,0,0}, {1,4,7,0,0,0}, {2,3,8,0,0,0}, {1,6,7,0,0,0}, {2,5,8,0,0,0}, {3,5,8,0,0,0}, {4,6,7,9,10,13}, {8,11,12,0,0,0}, {8,11,14,0,0,0}, {9,10,15,0,0,0}, {9,13,15,0,0,0}, {8,12,14,0,0,0}, {10,13,15,0,0,0}, {11,12,14,0,0,0} };

int counterSet, i, j, temp, counter, sizeOfVec ;

int routeCheck(int a, int b)
{
    //
    if(possibilities.size()!=0)
    {
        //
        sizeOfVec = 0 ;
        for(i=0; i<possibilities.size(); i++)
        {
            //
            sizeOfVec += possibilities[i].size();
        }
        if(sizeOfVec!=0)
        {
            //
            for(i=0; i< sizeOfVec; i++)
            {
                //
                if((possibilities[i][0] == a && possibilities[i][1] == b) || (possibilities[i][0] == b && possibilities[i][1] == a))
                {
                    //
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //
            return 1;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //
        return 1;
    }

}

int routeKeeper(int a, int b)
{
    //
    if(routeCheck(a,b) == 0)
    {
        //
        return 0;
    }
    else if(routeCheck(a,b) == 1)
    {
        //
        possibilities.push_back({a,b});
    }
}

void createRouteMap(int start, int end)
{
    //
    temp = j;

    for(j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        //
        cout << j << endl;
        if(cubes[start-1][j]==0)
        {
            //

        }
        else if(cubes[start-1][j]==end)   // if it is destination
        {
            //
            counter+=1;
            cout << "counter is: " <<counter << endl;
        }
        else if(routeCheck(start, cubes[start-1][j])==1)
        {
            //
            routeKeeper(start, cubes[start-1][j]);
            cout << "vector size is: " <<sizeOfVec << endl;
            createRouteMap(cubes[start-1][j], end);

        }
    }

    j=temp;
    possibilities.erase(possibilities.end());
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    counter = 0;
    createRouteMap(1, 15);
    cout<< counter << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My all code is above shared. I use bruteforce to count all possible ways to 15 th corner. However, eventhough there is no compiling error, terminal constantly get crashed. When I execute in debug mode(I use Dev-C++ 5.11) I get this error:

Program Received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation Fault

Of course I ve researched and found similar questions about my problem. But most of the suggestors pointed this was about the program trying to access a memory which is not belong to it. But the crazy thing is, I actually access all the memory, you can try in any editor, it runs first 3 iterations and use all the functions and variables. Output is like this:

[image]

Why is this happening? I would apreciate any suggestion and direction. Thanks.

Comment: Attach a debugger and see *where* the segfault occurs. That'll be 50% of the problem solved.

Comment: Also stop using global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code seems strange.

```
        sizeOfVec = 0 ;
        for(i=0; i<possibilities.size(); i++)
        {
            //
            sizeOfVec += possibilities[i].size();
        }
        if(sizeOfVec!=0)
        {
            //
            for(i=0; i< sizeOfVec; i++)
            {
                //
                if((possibilities[i][0]
```

`sizeOfVec` is used to index the vector `possibilities` but it count the total size of the vectors which are `possibilities` elements.
Many would suggest you to use a debugger for this.